# Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, asp

O código é esse:

```
<i> <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<!--#include virtual="aplicativos/arquivos.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="aplicativos/JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp" -->
<!--#include virtual="aplicativos/JSON_2.0.4.asp" -->
<!--#include virtual="aplicativos/validacao.asp"-->

<%
'----------------------------------------'
Dim d

set d = ConverteRequestParaDicionario(Request)

acao                = d.item("acao")
chbeneficio         = d.item("chbeneficio")
'----------------------------------------'
select case acao
    case "salvarDesempregado"  SalvarDesempregado()
end select
'----------------------------------------'
sub SalvarDesempregado

if d.item("nome") = "" then
        nome = "null"
else
    nome = "'" & d.item("nome") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("rg") = "" then
    rg = "null"
else
    rg = "'" & d.item("rg") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("cpf") = "" then
    cpf = "null"
else
    cpf = "'" & d.item("cpf") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("CTPSserie") = "" then
    CTPSserie = "null"
else
    CTPSserie = "'" & d.item("CTPSserie") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("ctps") = "" then
    ctps = "null"
else
    ctps = "'" & d.item("ctps") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("status") = "" then
    status = "null"
else
    status = "'" & d.item("status") & "'"

end if
if d.item("cep") = "" then
    cep = "null"
else
    cep = "'" & d.item("cep") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("endereco") = "" then
    endereco = "null"
else
    endereco = "'" & d.item("endereco") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("numero") = "" then
    numero = "null"
else
    numero = "'" & d.item("numero") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("bairro") = "" then
    bairro = "null"
else
    bairro = "'" & d.item("bairro") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("municipio") = "" then
    municipio = "null"
else
    municipio = "'" & d.item("municipio") & "'"

end if
if d.item ("complemento") = "" then
    complemento = "null"
else
    complemento = "'" & d.item("complemento") & "'"

end if
if d.item("estado") = "" then
    estado = "null"
else
    estado"'" & d.item("estado") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("email") = "" then
    email = "null"
else
    email = "'" & d.item("email") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("telefone") = "" then
    telefone = "null"
else
    telefone = "'" & d.item("telefone") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("celular") = "" then
    celular = "null"
else
    celular = "'" & d.item("celular") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("empresa") = "" then
    empresa = "null"
else
    empresa = "'" & d.item("empresa") & "'"

end if
if d.item ("profissao") = "" then
    profissao = "null"
else
    profissao = "'" & d.item("profissao") & "'"

end if
if d.item("dispensa") = "" then
    dispensa = "null"
else
    dispensa = "'" & d.item("dispensa") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("emprecep") = "" then
    emprecep = "null"
else
    emprecep = "'" & d.item("emprecep") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("empreendereco") = "" then
    empreendereco = "null"
else
    empreendereco = "'" & d.item("empreendereco") & "'"
end if

if d.item ("emprenumero") = "" then
    emprenumero = "null"
else
    emprenumero = "'" & d.item("emprenumero") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("emprecomplemento") = "" then
    emprecomplemento = "null"
else
    emprecomplemento = "'" & d.item("emprecomplemento") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("emprebairro") = "" then
    emprebairro = "null"
else
    emprebairro = "'" & d.item("emprebairro") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("empremunicipio") = "" then
    empremunicipio = "null"
else
    empremunicipio = "'" & d.item("empremunicipio") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("selo") = "" then
    selo = "null"
else
    selo = "'" & d.item("selo") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("entrega") = "" then
    entrega = "null"
else
    entrega = "'" & d.item("entrega") & "'"

end if

if d.item ("validade") = "" then
    validade = "null"
else
    validade = "'" & d.item("validade") & "'"

end if

SQL = "exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado " & chbeneficio & ",'" & nome & "','" & RG & "','" & CPF & "','" & cep & "','" & endereco & "','" & numero & "','" & bairro & "','" & municipio & "','" & complemento & "','" &estado & "','" & email & "','" & telefone & "','" & celular & "','" & CTPS & "','" & CTPSserie & "','" & empresa & "','" & profissao & "','" & dispensa & "','" & emprecep & "','" & empreendereco & "','" & emprenumero & "','" & emprecomplemento & "','" & emprebairro & "','" & empremunicipio & "','" & selo & "','"& entrega & "','" & validade & "'"

QueryToJSON(banco, SQL).flush
response.end
end sub
'----------------------------------------'
%> </i>
```

E o erro que recebo é sempre esse:

> ```
> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> /aplicativos/JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp, line 5
> ```

Eu já procurei em vários lugares, inclusive aqui e não consigo resolver esse erro. 
A procedure funciona, já testei no SQL Server.

Comment: tenta substituir essa linha SQL = "exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado " & chbeneficio & "','"

Comment: sua pergunta está muito mal formatada, nem vou tentar editar, pra não perder algum detalhe importante. No trecho `SQL = "exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado " & chbeneficio & ",'" & nome & "','" & RG & "','" &` a primeira concatenação pelo que parece estar faltando uma aspas simples.

Comment: tá bem dificil de visualizar isso tudo. 
Pelo tipo de erro provavelmente alguma variavel está com algum caractere reservado (exemplo aspas) e está quebrando o codigo.
Sugiro que voce fala um response.write e response.end pra cada variavel da query, até identificar.

Comment: Melissa, desculpe se está mal formatada, não sou boa pra explicar as coisas, e tbm é a primeira vez q pergunto algo. no chbeneficio, não coloquei aspas simples pq é um valor int e as outras são strings.

Comment: aa_asp eu tentei response.write e não consegui chegar na raiz do problema  T.T

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não entendo de ASP/VBSCRIPT mas as linguagens possuem muito em comum, o que permitiu compreender o que o código faz; e como o faz.

No código transcrito para este tópico observei que o conteúdo das variáveis foi delimitado por [ápices](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3strofo) (**'**). Por exemplo, se em `d.item("nome")` temos o conteúdo `Natália`, então no trecho

```
if d.item("nome") = "" then
        nome = "null"
else
    nome = "'" & d.item("nome") & "'"
end if
```

ao final teremos `'Natália'` em `nome`, com ápices no conteúdo da variável.

Ao utilizarmos o seguinte trecho de comando SQL

```
SQL = "exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado " & "'" & nome & "','" ...
```

o que teremos em `SQL` é

```
exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado ''Natália'',' ...
```

Ou seja, estão sobrando ápices...

Sugiro que no comando que monta `SQL` retire todos os ápices; ficaria assim:

```
SQL = "exec dbo.sp_desemp_insereDesempregado " & nome & "," ...
```

---

Se for necessário que haja espaço antes e após o operador de concatenação `&`, fique atenta ao trecho `&estado`.

Comment: mesmo com as alterações, o mesmo erro persiste

Comment: @Nath.S2 (1) Exiba na tela (`response.write`?) o conteúdo de `SQL`, no lugar de enviar para execução pelo SQL Server. Isto facilita analisar o que foi montado em `SQL` e encontrar prováveis causas. (2) Se possível acrescente ao final do texto de sua pergunta como ficou o novo comando de montagem de `SQL`; (3)  Se ainda assim não encontrar a causa, poderia acrescentar no final do texto de sua pergunta o conteúdo de `SQL`?